# Aws Rekognition: Error executing IndexFaces command

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Be informed, i'm trying to use aws rekognition indexFaces command to upload images to a 'collection'. I succesfully created the collection, but when i use the IndexFaces command, we are encountering the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\Rekognition\Exception\RekognitionException' with message 'Error executing "IndexFaces" on "https://rekognition.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://rekognition.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"__type":"InvalidImageFormatException","Code":"InvalidImageFormatException","Message":"Request has invalid image format (truncated...) InvalidImageFormatException (client): Request has invalid image format - {"__type":"InvalidImageFormatException","Code":"InvalidImageFormatException","Message":"Request has invalid image format"}' GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://rekognition.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"__type":"InvalidImageFormatException","Code":"InvalidImageFormatException","Message":"Request has invalid image format (truncated...) in /home/admin/web/mbracecloud.com/public_html/Aws/GuzzleHttp/Exception/RequestException.php:113 Stack trace: #0 /home/admi in /home/admin/web/mbracecloud.com/public_html/Aws/Aws/WrappedHttpHandler.php on line 195
```

We are using the following code to execute the command

```
$result = $s3->indexFaces([
        'CollectionId' => 'mbrace', 
        'ExternalImageId' => 'faces',
        'Image' => [ 
            'Bytes' => 'images/user.jpg',
            
        ],
        'MaxFaces' => 1,
        'QualityFilter' => 'NONE',
    ]);
```

I'm at loss as where i'm going wrong. Any ideas how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `indexFaces()` API call requires *either* `Bytes` (for providing the image in-line), *or* `S3Object` for specifying an image from Amazon S3.

If you are referencing a file from the local disk, then `Bytes` will need to contain the **contents** of the image file -- but your code is providing filename. This is why it is generating an `InvalidImageFormatException`.

You should read the contents of the file and provide that as the Bytes.